# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS after updating Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, arm, apk

I updated my Android Studio to the following version:

[image]

And started to get the following error:

```
The APK failed to install. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113
```

while trying to install ARM APK on X86_64 emulator.

I am not sure what version I had before, but ARM APK installed successfully on my X86_64 emulator with that version on this emulator:

[image]

Comment: I would try to install an ARM APK from a different source to see if it is the emulator or your build project.

Comment: @Robert It is not build. I have an APK that installed on old version of the emulator and does not install on the new version.

Comment: @Robert the emulator also stopped displaying my game (that has only ARM APKs) in Google Play, so definitely something changed in the emulator.

Comment: Why do you install the latest API33 image. Use an older image and it may work again.

Comment: @Robert successfully installed my ARM APK on Android 12 emulator (API 31).